# C++ interpolate array with cosine

Tags: c++, arrays, interpolation, trigonometry

I got this function from [this website]http://paulbourke.net/miscellaneous/interpolation/):

```
double CosineInterpolate(
   double y1,double y2,
   double mu)
{
   double mu2;

   mu2 = (1-cos(mu*PI))/2;
   return(y1*(1-mu2)+y2*mu2);
}
```

How do I use this to interpolate an array? Here's how I'd be calling the function.

```
Interpolate(point_a, point_b, number_of_positions_between_the_points, position)
```

e.g.

```
for (int i = 0; i < ArrayOfPoints.size()-1; ++i) {
    double point_a = ArrayOfPoints[i];
    double point_b = ArrayOfPoints[i+1];
    for (int j = 0; j < 2048; ++j){
        array[j] = Interpolate(point_a, point_b, 2048, j)
    }
}
```

Comment: It's just a question of converting `number_of_positions_between_the_points` and `position` into `mu`. Trivial math.

Comment: How do you "convert to mu?" Sorry I just don't understand this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the number of positions between the points, and then you have the current position. Think of `mu` as a percentage of the linear distance between the first point and the second that is determined by the current position, and the total number of positions. That is:

```
mu = (double)current_position / number_of_positions_between_the_points;
```

That will give you values between `0` and `1`, in fixed increments, determined by how many positions you want to have between the points.

*Hint*: In your loop, `j` is the current position.

The other thing that you have to deal with is that you are calling a function named `Interpolate(point_a, point_b, 2048, j)` but you haven't shown the implementation for that function. Instead, you have the `CosineInterpolate` function. Presumably you wanted to abstract the interpolation method by invoking `CosineInterpolate` from `Interpolate`. The first part of the answer tells you how to do that. I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your help!... hmm, the whole "0 to 1" might be a problem, because I need point_a value to point_b value. Unfortunately that's not the end of my problem. I'm even not asking the right question. I think what I really need is called "smoothing" (not interpolation).

Comment: @ElanHickler "0 to 1" is not going to be a problem. That's what mu needs to be in that equation. Think of it as a percentage (0 = 0% 1= 100%). That is what makes the interpolated points appear between `point_a` and `point_b` (point_a is 0%, point_b is 100%). To make it easier, just try to do the math with 4 points between.. mu will take the values of: 0.25 0.5, 0.75, 1.